# Nested For Loop in Jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am making a nested for loop in Jinja / Python Flask.

If I hard code the values, then it works fine.  Am I missing something in the Jinja template?

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
    {% for column in Columns %}
        <td>{{ column }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>

       {% for row in rows %}
           <tr>
                {% for column in Columns %}
                    <td>{{ row.column }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
           </tr>
       {% endfor %}

</table>
```

By the way, the output is nothing when it is not hardcoded.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
    {% for column in Columns %}
        <td>{{ column }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>

       {% for row in rows %}
           <tr>
                {% for column in Columns %}
                    <td>{{ row[column] }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
           </tr>
       {% endfor %}

</table>
```

The only changed needed was to change `{{ row.column }}` to `{{ row[column] }}` on line 11.

Comment: I get:

Could not parse the remainder: '[column]' from 'row[column]'

Looked through all the answers here and none explain why this error occurs on array index notation. Can anyone help? Thks. Django 2.2.6