# Reference variable in for loop embedded in for loop

Tags: python, flask

I have a piece of code whereby I want three records for each year from 2019-2029. I have used a for loop to achieve this but I want my form element names to change to reflect this. The below code will produce the ten lines but each line will have the same three id's eg Forecast_2019_1, Forecast_2019_2 and Forecast_2019_3.

I was hoping I could include the i variable in each name but not sure how this is achieved.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Option 1</p></th>
      <th>Option 2</p></th>
      <th>Option 3</p></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for i in range(2019, 2029) %}
      <tr>
        <td>
          {{ i }}
        </td>
        <td>
          {% for message in form.Forecast_2019_1.errors %}
             <div>{{ message }}</div>
          {% endfor %}
          {{ form.Forecast_2019_1 }}
        </td>
        <td>
          {% for message in form.Forecast_2019_2.errors %}
             <div>{{ message }}</div>
          {% endfor %}
          {{ form.Forecast_2019_2 }}
        </td>
        <td>
          {% for message in form.Forecast_2019_3.errors %}
             <div>{{ message }}</div>
          {% endfor %}
          {{ form.Forecast_2019_3 }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The output I would want is as follows if i change the range to (2019,2021):

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Option 1</p></th>
      <th>Option 2</p></th>
      <th>Option 3</p></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        2019
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="Forecast_2019_1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="Forecast_2019_2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="Forecast_2019_3">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        2019
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="Forecast_2020_1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="Forecast_2020_2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="Forecast_2020_3">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        2019
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="Forecast_2021_1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="Forecast_2021_2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="Forecast_2021_3">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want the output to look like? I'm not following your question.

Comment: @PatrickConwell added an example of my expected html output if that helps.

Comment: [Nested loop in a jinja template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34584426/nested-for-loop-in-jinja2) and [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) is what you need.

Comment: @Fian could you elaborate a bit as I'm not sure how to use getattr for this purpose.