# Using Jinja2 and for loop

Tags: python, jinja2

I am very new to Jinja2 and I want to show 3 different things in line, repeating it 2 times so I get 3x3 block. Here is my code now:

```
{% for item in recommendations('someID', 3) %}
```

This gives me only 3 things which are displayed vertically. How can I make it to display 3 things horizontally and then repeat it 2 more times? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look into this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34584426/nested-for-loop-in-jinja2 To me it seems that you are trying to go for a nested for loop

Comment: @EvgeniiKlepilin Not exactly. I am trying to display certain things from array, 3 times in one row and then doing so 2 more times.

Comment: Can you provide the desired result? What is the output you want to achieve?

Comment: @EvgeniiKlepilin I want to write a b c, then in the next row d e f and in the next row g h i using Jinja2 and for loop taking these values from array.

Answer (score 0):

If we take a function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks) question's answer, and prepare our array by splitting it into a desired length chunks, so that we have array of a format `[['a'. 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]`, we will be able to use a simple nested for loop in Jinja to accomplish this task.

```
def chunks(lst, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]
```

---

```
{% for subArray in array %}
       {% for element in subArray %}
           {{ element }}, 
       {% endfor %}
       <br />
{% endfor %}
```

This should result in:

```
a,b,c,
d,e,f,
g,h,i,
```